# Writing to S3 File stream

Tags: http, amazon-s3, outputstream

I have a HttpURLConnection connection object to s3 file and I am writing to the connection stream as follows. It works for plain text ,zip files. But when I write a tar.gz file , after complete when I check the uploaded file. It is corrupted.

I did binary compare some characters looks to be different. What can be the reason for some characters getting changed?

```
     URL s3FileUrl = new URL(s3Fileurl);
     HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) s3FileUrl.openConnection();
     connection.setDoOutput(true);
     connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
     OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                 connection.getOutputStream());

      FileInputStream fIn =  new FileInputStream("somefile");
        int i;
         while ((i = fIn.read()) != -1)
         {
             out.write(i);
         }

       fIn.close();
       out.close();
```

Comment: This code appears to throw a URL not found exception for me asis.